# Why won't Tkinter executable capture key combinations?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm building an tkinter app on Python 3.7 and creating an .exe with Pyinstaller 3.5 in Windoows 10. When running the code from the IDE, all intended keyboard commands work as expected. However, in the executable, key combinations do not work while single key presses are fine.

Here is some test code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.StringVar()
lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=txt)

def key_handle(event):
    global txt
    txt.set(event.keysym)

def kc_handle(event):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo('Key Combo', 'Key Combo pressed')

root.bind('<Key>', key_handle)
root.bind('<Alt-b>', kc_handle)

lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Pyinstaller is then invoked as `pyinstaller -w -F key_test.py`.

One thing I do know is that the order of the binds doesn't seem to make a difference. How do I get key combinations working in the executable?

Comment: did you run .exe in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see if it show error messages? What if you remove `bind('<Key>')` ?

Comment: when I run it (without IDLE) then I got error `'tkinter' has no attribute 'messagebox'` because you forgot `import tkinter.messagebox`. IDLE is built using `tkinter` and it could import it for own use and your code could work without this import but it will not work normally.

Comment: Running the executable from terminal did not give any error message. Importing `tkinter.messagebox` does fix the test code for me. This solution also works for the original app. (in the app I was using `tkinter.simpledialog`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDLE` is built using `tkinter` and it could import all needed modules for own use and your code could work correctly but when you run it without `IDLE` then you have to import all modules which you use in code. In your example it will be

```
import tk.messagebox
```

---

**BTW:** Often similar problem is with `mainloop()`. `IDLE` aready runs `mainloop()` so code may work without own `mainloop()`. But normally (without `IDLE`) it needs to use `mainloop()`. It is good to check code in `terminal/console/cmd.exe` to see if it gives any errors.